# sql query finding most often level appear

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Student` in SQL Server with these columns:

```
[ID], [Age], [Level]
```

I want the query that returns each age value that appears in `Students`, and ﬁnds the level value that appears most often. For example, if there are more `'a'` level students aged 18 than 'b' or  'c' it should print the pair `(18, a)`.

I am new to SQL Server and I want a simple answer with nested query.

Comment: +1 nicely structured and clear question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option with ROW_NUMBER ranking function in the ORDER BY clause. WITH TIES used when you want to return two or more rows that tie for last place in the limited results set.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES age, level
FROM dbo.Student
GROUP BY age, level
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY age ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

Or the second version of the query using amount each pair of age and level, and max values of count pair age and level per age.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT age, level, COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
             MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY age) AS mCnt
      FROM dbo.Student
      GROUP BY age, level
      )x
WHERE x.cnt = x.mCnt
```

Demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f847a/1)

Comment: @alexanderFedorako: can  this be written without row_number( ), over  and partition by commands ? as i dont know how these work ..

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select age, level, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by age order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from student s
      group by age, level
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The inner query aggregates the data to count the number of levels for each age.  The `row_number()` enumerates these for each age (the `partition by` with the largest first).  The `where` clause then chooses the highest values.

In the case of ties, this returns just one of the values.  If you want all of them, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: I think you meant to alias your sub-query as t, not s.

Answer (score 1):

```
with combinations as (
  select age, level, count(*) occurrences
  from Student
  group by age, level
)
select age, level
from combinations c
where occurrences = (select max(occurrences)
                     from combinations
                     where age = c.age)
```

This finds every age and level combination in the Students table and counts the number of occurrences of each level.
Then, for each age/level combination, find the one whose occurrences are the highest for that age/level combination.  Return the age and level for that row.

This has the advantage of not being tied to SQL Server - it's vanilla SQL.  However, a window function like Gordon pointed out may perform better on SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderFedorenko - good call.  What I needed to use was a CTE so that I could refer to the same object twice.

Answer (score 1):

Another option but will require later version of sql-server:

```
;WITH x AS
(
SELECT  age, 
        level, 
        occurrences = COUNT(*) 
FROM    Student
GROUP BY age, 
        level
)
SELECT *
FROM   x x
WHERE  EXISTS (
              SELECT * 
              FROM   x y
              WHERE  x.occurrences > y.occurrences
              )
```

I realise it doesn't quite answer the question as it only returns the age/level combinations where there are more than one level for the age.

Maybe someone can help to amend it so it includes the single level ages aswell in the result set: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d597b/9